# The 'Links to Your Site' section of Webmaster Tools all resolve to one domain

Tags: google, google-search-console

In Google's Webmaster Tools, under 'Search Traffic', and then 'Links to Your Site', there are 5 domains and 3 of them are old domains of our own and a development domain that are all actually the same site.

I have proper 301 redirects on these domains so traffic is all routed to the correct one. But is there any way to tell Google that all of these domains are actually the same? And that they shouldn't be counted as separate links to the site.

Answer (score 1):

*There is no option within Google Search Console*

But it can be done by telling Google not to index the development domain using [no-index](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93710?hl=en), but if you want to index the development domain and just discount the links then you need to use [no-follow](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/96569?hl=en) on your links.

Comment: That would certainly fix the dev domain, but I can't no-index the others because they all resolve to the proper domain.

Comment: Domains that do not resolve will eventually drop from Google's index which is just as equivalent to doing a noindex since the outcome remains the same. So if the sub domain doesn't work or returns a 410 gone... then there's nothing else you can do.

Comment: So, are you saying that if I dump the 301s and stop using the domain, it will disappear? But if I keep the redirects it will probably stay?

Comment: Sorry but my answer ignores the part about you redirecting. You should no-index the development site if it adds no value to the main site. Your other domains that have similar content and a clean link profile should 301 to your main domain, ideally relevant pages. When you 301 from one site to another, your not associating them as so to speak but you are passing the SEO gained from one site to the other.

Comment: This problem goes back 20 years to when domains had a certain character limit. We couldn't get our full company name so it was abbreviated. Eventually the character limit went away and we started using our full name, but leaving the old name active for existing links. So now, if OLD.com 301s to NEW.com, how do I noindex OLD.com without harming NEW.com?

Comment: Using a 301 from old to new is equal to noindex since Google doesn't index pages or sites that 301 to another because they only index the destination. 301 redirect will pass SEO from old to new.